# How to optimize two foreach loops with large data sets

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, foreach

At present each complete loop is taking 3.5 seconds this would take 63 hours to run at it's current pace. Is there any better way to optimize this loop? The data sets are rather large and one has about 75,677 the other has around 700,000.

```
foreach(string i in dataText.Skip(1).OrderBy(x => x.Split(',')[0]))
{
    string[] textparts = i.Split(',');
    foreach(string j in newExcelList.Skip(3))
    {
        string[] excelparts = j.Split(',');
        if(textparts[0]  == excelparts[0])
        {
            sw.WriteLine($"{excelparts[0]}\tN25\tPRIM\t{excelparts[1]}\t{excelparts[2]}\t{excelparts[3]}\t{excelparts[4]}\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `newExcelList` change in any way during each iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: Are you aware that using an `OrderBy` causes that the whole dataText is read? (what is it? a file? and array?)

Comment: I don't see any changes made to the `newExcelList` collection,(like Peter says) So This can be pre-calculated before the loops. You are splitting the same data over and over again there.

Comment: I did remove the orderby and sort the list just once and not on each iteration. It's a file I read into memory.

Comment: @WigSnatcher did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

None of the contents of this data appear to change from iteration to iteration. You can therefore create a 2D array of both `datatext` and `excelparts` at the start, before either loop. Otherwise you're redundantly splitting all these strings an insane number of times, and almost always not even using all the values. So try this instead:

```
string[][] dataTextRows =
    dataText.Skip(1).Select(dt => dt.Split(','))
    .OrderBy(dtrow => dtrow[0])
    .ToArray();

string[][] excelListRows =
    newExcelList.Skip(3).Select(el => el.Split(','))
    .ToArray();

foreach (string[] textparts in dataTextRows)
{
    foreach (string[] excelparts in excelListRows)
    {
        if (textparts[0] == excelparts[0])
        {
            sw.WriteLine($"{excelparts[0]}\tN25\tPRIM\t{excelparts[1]}\t{excelparts[2]}\t{excelparts[3]}\t{excelparts[4]}\t");
        }
    }
}
```

But if you want to make a really pro-level move, you could avoid the second loop all together by using a `Dictionary` keyed to the value of the first column:

```
var excelListDict = excelListRows.ToDictionary(row => row[0], row => row);

foreach (string[] textparts in dataTextRows)
{
    if (!excelListDict.TryGetValue(textparts[0], out var excelparts))
        continue;
    sw.WriteLine($"{excelparts[0]}\tN25\tPRIM\t{excelparts[1]}\t{excelparts[2]}\t{excelparts[3]}\t{excelparts[4]}\t");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. This has been quite helpful

Comment: Had to double back on this one. How can we split this list of string only once but still identify each split string outside of a loop? can you provide a code snippet example?

Comment: Oh no problem thank you for letting me know. I will play around a bit and update the answer.

Comment: Any update on this one?

Comment: @WigSnatcher yes see above.

Comment: I wouldn't call the dictionary a pro-level move. It's basic knowledge which any rookie developer must know about.

Comment: Let no opportunity to condescend pass us by..